# Generating many URLs in one Symfony Controller action

Tags: php, symfony

I have an action with annotation route to "showAllLinks"

```
    /**  
    * @param Request $request  
    * @return Response  
    * @Route("/showAllLinks/")
    **/
```

When that action is accessed, I would like to generate URLs (relative and absolute) to several other actions I wrote in the same controller. Is that possible? So far I've tried with several URLs being generated and pushed into array which then would be included in response, but from what I see, Symfony is either asking for

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.
```

See action below:

```
public function showAllLinksAction(Request $request)
{
    $linksArr = [];
    $url1 = $this->generateUrl('helloWorld', [], 302, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $linksArr[] = $url1;
    $url2 = $this->generateUrl('goodbye', [], 302, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $linksArr[] = $url2;
    $url3 = $this->generateUrl('welcome', [], 302, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $linksArr[] = $url3;
    $url4 = $this->generateUrl('welcome', [], 302, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $linksArr[] = $url4;

    return new Response($linksArr);
}
```

Comment: Try with `return new JsonResponse($linksArr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array to the response object, you should pass an string. These are the params of the response object, from the Symfony documentation:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response(
    'Content',
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    array('content-type' => 'text/html')
);
```

I think you could use

```
$response = new Response('Content');
```

or

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent('Content');
```

In any case, the 'Content' parameter is a string. You are trying to set $linksArr, which is an array. This should work, although may not be the result you want to achieve:

```
return new Response(implode(",", $linksArr));
```